# javascript regular expression match() result

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what I put into Chrome's browser console

```
>> 'abc,de.fg\nhi'.match(/.*/g)
["abc,de.fg", "", "hi", ""]
```

Why are there empty strings in the result?

A separate question:

```
>> 'abc\ndef\n'.match(/(.*)\n/)
["abc
", "abc"]
>> 'abc\ndef\n'.match(/.*\n/)
["abc
"]
```

Why does the first one give two values? I cannot find any documentation that indicates groups (parentheses) should be appended to match results. This does not occur when using the `/g` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your second question, if there are groups present the result array contains the whole match in the position zero and the group matches in subsequent positions.

Comment: I believe you are correct in that observation, I came up with the same explanation but it does not apply when using a /g modifier!

Comment: With the global match flag the result array holds every match in order so I guess there is no room for group matches.

Answer (score 0):

The * in your regular expression matches zero or more characters. The . matches anything except a new line. Therefore, it gets split on the newline and matches the empty space before and after.

```
'abc,de.fg\nhi'.match(/.+/g)
["abc,de.fg", "hi"]
```

Comment: Yes, using the `+` is clearly the way to go for most cases. But I'm wondering why there is an empty string at the end? If, as you say it matches an empty before and after the `\n`, why wouldn't the result instead be `["abc,de.fg", "", "", "hi", ""]`?

Comment: The regular expression has already matched nothing (since it does not match the \n) and has continued on from that point. After that, it finds the "hi" portion of the string (since it will find as many characters as it can) and matches that. Then when it reaches the end of the string, it matches another empty character.